# Add css to asp.net core mvc file

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started a course about ASP.NET Core MVC. I have done some programming before and I don't have a problem with CSS or C# in general, but now in VS with MVC, I have no idea how to add the CSS.

So, the problem:

When you start your MVC project you get this default site, I completed the site as I want, but now I want to add the CSS to the different links. In the navbar, I have a home, which is easily configured with the site.css and layout page, but my other link in the navbar, let's say the navbar link about me. If I want to add my CSS to that file, how/where do I do that? Do I have to link it somehow in the layout page or how do I get it right?

Comment: you can add a link to CSS file anywhere in a HTML file, it doesn't need to be in the header - that's just a convention. Or you can use a `<style>` block directly in the markup. This has nothing much to do with MVC, and certainly nothing to do with visual studio or C# or asp.net in general. I've adjusted your tags.

Comment: The main reason to put CSS in the layout page in asp.net mvc is if you want the same CSS to be applied to every page (which mostly, you do. People don't tend to have per-page CSS very much, it usually just leads to inconsistent appearance and/or too much maintenance.). So unless your "about" page is going to have a completely different style and theme than your other pages, I suggest just adding whatever CSS you need into the main Site.css file so it's consistent with the other pages.

Comment: Ahh okay! So usually you just manage css in the site.css for all the different pages? Like this line, which have been modified by classmates, but this line of code is in a cshtml file, so some of the styling could be applied in the cshtml files aswell? <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:limegreen">Add New</a>

Comment: Well that's an inline style which applies only to the specific element it's written on. That's fine and useful sometimes, but again to create consistency and avoid repetition you'd want to set universal styles in your CSS file(s) as much as possible, e.g. to get all links (or all kind with a certain class) looking the same way.

Comment: Got it! But to set universal styles, I read about it a bit yesterday, don't really get it though. Lets say I have my home button, then the "about me" button, if i wanna be able to set some styling to that site, do i create a new css file like the site.css or do i change it in the site.css? Dont really know how to get access to the different classes in the "about me" page.

Comment: If your about page and your home page both use the layout page, and the layout page links to the site.css, then any styles you define in site.css will be applied in both pages (and in any other page which uses your layout page). I thought I'd explained that already

Comment: P.s. if you want to learn the basics of CSS you should do so separately without the extra features of MVC getting in the way. You should do basic HTML and CSS training (and possibly JavaScript and c#) before tackling MVC. MVC is something which brings all those tools together in a useful framework, but somewhat presumes some basic knowledge of those building blocks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

try it in your *.cshtml view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "title";
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/YourStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).